# "CKEDITOR" not defined when using Email Publisher

Tags: visualforce, email, case, richtextarea, publisher

I'm currently having troubles to make a custom email sender page for the Case tab. I needed to automatically fill some fields depending on some parameters from the case.

It almost works, but when I load an email template which contains an image, the text area disappears and the console shows:

> ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

I tried several ways to fix it but nothing helped.

Here is the VisualForce page used:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="Ctrl_ActionsCase" action="{!sendEmailInitFrom}">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    // Page Init
    j$(document).ready(function() {
        // Set FROM addresse
        var optionFromAdresse = j$("select[id*=from] option[value*='{!addressEmailFrom}']");
        if(optionFromAdresse.length > 0) {
            optionFromAdresse[0].selected = true;
        }   
    });
</script>

<apex:emailPublisher id="emailPublisher"
        entityId="{!case.id}"
        width="500px"
        title="{!$Label.Email_Action_Title}"
        expandableHeader="false"
        autoCollapseBody="false"
        showAdditionalFields="false"
        showTemplates="true"
        fromVisibility="selectable"         
        toAddresses="{!case.contact.email}"
        toVisibility="readOnly"
        bccVisibility="hidden"
        ccVisibility="hidden"
        emailBody=""
        emailBodyHeight="4em"
        subject=""
        showSendButton="true"
        sendButtonName="{!$Label.Send_Email_Button}"
/>
```

Regards.

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add script tag on your page [using CDN](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/):

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

or [download ckeditor package](http://ckeditor.com/download) and embed local script:

```
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
```